# Explicitly include assembly in Linker process Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-linker

I'm working on Xamarin.Forms project but my Xamarin.iOS project is including some assemblies which I'm not using anywhere. I wanted to exclude those library from my project and not to be included in my IPA. Linker is set to "Don't Link" and I cant use "SDK Assembly only" as application stops working.
I tried using "--linkskip=assemblyname" in mtouch configuration but, I guess its opposite to what i want. I want all the assemblies to be included in my build but want to exclude specific assembly.

Comment: I suggest you figure out why linking is not working with your app instead.

Comment: Thanks @Cheesebaron for quick reply. I'm continuously working on it, along with it I thought of give a try to this approach. If is there any way to include specific assembly in linker process during build process, I would be able to proceed.

Comment: If reducing app size is the end goal you can look here but I do not think you can do what you are trying to do: https://medium.com/@hakimgulamali88/reducing-the-app-size-in-xamarin-deep-dive-7ddc9cb12688

Comment: In Visual Studio look at Solution Explorer Reference Tab to see what libraries are being included.  You can delete libraries that aren't being used.

Comment: Hi @jdweng I tried that approach also but, the assembly which I want to delete is in Xamarin.iOS.dll which I cant delete from Visual Studio Solution Explorer Reference Tab.

Comment: tTen it is needed.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. tTen?